# Want large \mathbb{N} in Wordpress

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, online

I am using LaTeX in a Wordpress environment. Can I produce a large version of `$\mathbb{N}$`.
I have tried using `\large`, `\bf`, `\mathbf` and `\mathsymbol` but nothing works

Comment: I'd try `$\mbox{\Large$\mathbb{N}$}$`

Comment: @egreg: Normally, a WordPress site does not use `\mbox` and it does not know the font size commands neither

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.